# Is adding functions to a namespace/module after imports an anti-pattern?

Tags: python

In my python codebase I have several open source dependencies, eg. pandas, plotly, etc. Some of these are missing some functions that I'd rather they have.

I sometimes add functions to these libraries after importing them because it seems better to me to keep some tightly coupled functions in the same namespace.

To give you an example, consider the plotting library `plotly.express`

```py
import plotly.express as px 

# some of the functions in the px package
px.line(...)
px.bar(...)
px.sunburst(...)
```

I sometimes like to do this:

```
def _my_candlestick_plot(df, ...)->'plotly figure':
    ...

px.candlestick = _my_candlestick_plot
```

This allows me to later in my code do:

```
px.candelstick(df, ...)
```

etc...

Are there any good/bad reasons to do this? Ie. is this blasphemy or a reasonable software development approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This technique is known as [monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching), see also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). Monkey patching can also mean other forms of applying patches to existing classes at run time, adding own functions to a module is just one use case for this technique.

In Python, this is quite common. When you do this to add some functions to an existing package, you shold be careful to choose function names which are unlikely to collide with existing function names, or with names which might be used in a future release of the module you are patching.

In C#, for example, there is a mechanism called "extension methods", which provides language support for exactly this scenario. Unlike to Python, however, a name collision would automatically result in an error during compilation. In Python, this might introduce some silent error, so be careful which names you are choosing.

Comment: Thank you, good to know it's a thing. It can help to centralize functionality as oposed to having px and another namespace for "my_plotting_functions", etc...

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your application, I would much rather see two separate imports, and either one namespace that you provide, or better two  separate module names. Why? When I see px.candlestick, I am going to consult the standard plotly docs, and I will not find relevant documentation. I would much rather that you communicate to the reader that this is a candlestick function that is layered on top of plotly.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious downside here is, as noted in J_H's answer that there's nothing clearly indicating that you have done this unless someone is looking at the module where you did replaced the names.  There are also potentially confusing results if the order of the modules being loaded changes: suddenly code that was using your custom function could use the standard one or vice-versa.

If this a single module script, then those issues are probably irrelevant. If this is a multi-module application, you might want to consider creating a package and putting your overrides/monkey-patches in the `__init__` module.

Another option you might want to consider is something like how FastAPI redeclares Starlette functions in it's namespace. That is, add all the functions from these libraries (and monkey-patches) to your namespace.  Then it is clear which functions you are using and also it would clearly indicate where people should look to see exactly how they are defined. Here, that might look like:

```py
# file: px_ext.py
"""All plotly-express APIs, along with some extensions."""
from plotly.express import *

def candlestick(...): ...
```

```py
# file: consumer.py
import .px_ext as px

px.candlestick(...)
```

Comment: Yes, the modifications are in the __init__ of the module, and this is a single module application.